# ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment variables work in Simulator but not on Device

Tags: ios, xcode

My environment variables work on the simulator, but when I try to run on my device, they return nil. Perhaps they are only meant to work on a simulator, in which case, what is the ideal alternative for a device?

Note: This only occurs when I change the scheme to not launching the app by default after building.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about variables set in the scheme:
[image: screen in question]

It makes sense to me that they would only be passed to an instance of your app that is being launched directly from Xcode as these variables sound like they are part of the Xcode environment - I believe they are only for debugging.